# Adding supervisor node on Webots R2019a

Tags: webots

I am very new in Webots simulator as well as in robotics. I am using new open source version of webots. I believes it is not compatible with older versions of webots. I tested some old programs available on GitHub. That doesn't work. In some programs I saw Supervisor node. But I didn't saw any supervisor node on Webots R2019a. How can I add supervisor node on Webots version R2019a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Supervisor node was deprecated in Webots R2019a. But it should still be working (thanks to a PROTO mechanism). To create a new supervisor in Webots 2019a, you should create a Robot node and set its supervisor field to TRUE. See the documentation about it here: https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/supervisor

Comment: I have two more questions. 1)Description of the Robot node on Webots says that in order to access full feature we have to purchase pro licence. Then why are you saying it is open source as well as only for support we have to pay? 2)Your example program on curriculum> Advanced_particle_swarm_optimization.wbt is not working. Why? It crashes sometime sometime it doesn't works. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Webots R2019a is fully open source and provides all the features previously available with a license of Webots PRO. I guess you are referring to the documentation of a previous version of Webots.

Comment: How does one set the supervisor field to TRUE ? There's no setter and the constructor has no arguments. When I use the Supervisor constructor there's still the "ignoring illegal call to wb_supervisor_node_get_from_def() in a 'Robot' controller." error